# jQuery 3D tag cloud plugin doesn't work in IE and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

Does anyone know why Jquery 3D tag cloud plugin doesn't work in IE and Chrome?

See [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/tagcloud/)

Comment: Their demo doesn't work aswell. In chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin works fine in Chrome and IE11 when you run it on JSBin and embed the JS code on the page (http://jsbin.com/IJUGEDA/1).

My guess is that the demo isn't linking to the JS correctly, or GitHub isn't serving the correct MIME Type. Taken from Chrome console:

`Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/dynamicguy/tagcloud/master/src/tagcloud.jquery.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

This would indicate that GitHub is serving the file as plain text rather than Javascript, and the browser doesn't execute it.